# Will threads of executor automatically exit after an Android app being closed

Tags: android, multithreading, executor

I'm implement a simple network framework that running upon the executor framework. Since I think it's unreliable to rely the client to shut down my `NetworkOperator`, I had provided a app-shared singleton for the client.

And then, what will happen if the instance of `Application` being destroyed(that is, the user close our app). Will the thread of executor framework being destroyed? (I know that in a C app, if the `main` function returned, the process will exit. Is the main thread of Android APP also has a `main`? If it does, will this behavior be changed as Android will cached the closed app?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. you are correct.

The main thread of the android app a main and it is the UI thread.

If you want to do some asynchronous task wven when your app is killed, then use a thread within a started service instead of simply using thread/asyncTask

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `AsyncTask`(you remind me) uses a `Executor` and does not shut it down too.